# VB6 - make the result numbers i a sequence

Tags: vba, vb6

Hello i have this VB6 code

```
Public Sub ShowOperations()

    Dim Drw As Drawing
    Set Drw = App.ActiveDrawing

    Dim Ops As Operations
    Set Ops = Drw.Operations

    Dim Op As Operation
    For Each Op In Ops

        For Each SubOp In Op.SubOperations

            Debug.Print Op.Number & "-" & Op.SubOperations.Count

        Next SubOp
    Next Op
End Sub
```

In operations can be more sub operations.
but my result is like this

```
1-1
2-2
2-2
3-1
4-3
4-3
4-3
5-1
```

As you can see for operation 2 it show me total 2sub operations... but i need that the reseult will be

```
1-1
2-1
2-2
3-1
4-1
4-2
4-3
5-1
```

can me somebody help with this...

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a SubOp counter:

```
Dim nSubOp As Long '<--| declare a SubOp counter
For Each Op In Ops
    nSubOp = 0 '<--| initialize SubOp counter
    For Each SubOp In Op.SubOperations
        nSubOp = nSubOp + 1 '<--| update SubOp counter
        Debug.Print Op.Number & "-" & nSubOp
    Next SubOp
Next Op
```